# subprocess for long string of commands python error message

Tags: python

I want to write a python script to execute to following line:

```
ls -1 -d ??? | cut -c 1-2 | sort | uniq | while read NN; do echo $NN; tar -cjf fcllistRPC_${NN}.bz2 ${NN}?; done
```

I tried:

```
def loop(jobname):
  """
  Loop over gen_fcl output and store as tarbull
  """
  loop = ["ls", "-1", "-d", "???", "|", "cut", "-c", "1-2", "|", "sort", "|", "uniq", "|", "while", "read", "NN;", "do", "echo", "$NN;", "tar", "-cjf", "fcllist_"+str(jobname)+".bz2", "${NN}?;", "done"]
  subproc = subprocess.run(loop)
  return subproc
```

But I am seeing this error:

```
ls: invalid option -- 'j'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you make sure that the original command is the correct one? Can you run that one in your terminal?

Comment: yes, it works, the idea is that I have a directory called 000 or 001 etc. and I want to tar all these up

Comment: `subprocess.run()` runs a *single* command - `ls` in your case, with about 20 parameters (most of which being things that `ls` doesn't understand).  Generally, multiple commands require multiple `subprocess` calls - but that won't work in this case, since some parts of your command line (`while`, `read`) are inherently shell built-ins that *cannot* be run as standalone processes.  The simplest solution would be to run the whole command (as a string, rather than a list), with `shell=True` so that the shell handles all of the individual commands for you.

Comment: None of this is hard to replace with native Python code. Write in shell script if you are not using Python's facilities anyway.

Answer (score 0):

in your code you have `-cjf`. each letter is an "option" for a command. this is causing the error. if you remove it it will run

also if you want it to run a line of code then run that line of code.

```
codeToRun = "ls -1 -d ??? | cut -c 1-2 | sort | uniq | while read NN; do echo $NN; tar -cjf fcllistRPC_${NN}.bz2 ${NN}?; done"
subproc = subprocess.run(codeToRun)
```